# Action method is not called the second time

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets, uiinclude

I am using templates, which in my main template I have a

```
<ui:include src="#{navBean.content}.xhtml">
```

My problem is that the action method of any bean, is not called having been run on the previous page . Here is an example where when you click the menu on the first page, an ajax call is made, the action method is executed and the page content loaded. By clicking the link on the loaded page(page1) the action method is not executed.

Config: jsf 2.2.9 | primefaces 5.1 | tomcat 8.0.3

template.xhtml

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h:form>
            <p:slideMenu>
                <p:submenu label="Cat 1">
                    <p:menuitem value="page1" action="#{navBean.changeMenuContent('page1')}" update=":change"/>
                    <p:menuitem value="bla"/> 
                </p:submenu>
            </p:slideMenu>
        </h:form>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h:form id="change">
            <ui:include src="/#{navBean.content}.xhtml"/>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

navBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "navBean")
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationBean
{
    private String content = "index";
    public void changeMenuContent(String content)
    {
        setContent(content);
    }
    //get set...
}
```

page1.xhtml

```
<p:commandLink value="teste" action="#{navBean.changeMenuContent('page2')}" ajax="false"/>
```

The page2 has only one `<p: outputLabel />`, for test.

I've tried with `p:commandLink` and `h:commandLink`

Thanks!

Comment: Does your included page (page1.xhtml) have a form tag?

Comment: No, only the commandLink.

Comment: Hi @VitorFreitas have you solved this? I'm with the same problem with commandButton. Using primefaces 5.0 jsf sun 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Try add `update=":change"`on:

```
<p:commandLink value="teste" action="#{navBean.changeMenuContent('page2')}" ajax="false" update=":change />
```

See the `changeMenuContent` is `void`, so it does not cause page navigation.

So you need to run "update" manually.

See also, that your Bean is @RequestScope, therefore its contents are recreated on every request.

So the most recommended would change the Bean to @SessionScope, and:

```
<p:commandLink value="teste" actionListener="#{navBean.changeMenuContent('page2')}" update=":change />
```

Comment: I put as SessionScoped, and added the update, and had the same result as above.

Comment: Changed action="" for actionListener="" ?

Comment: In `p:commandLink` you added ajax ="false", but in `p:menuitem` not.

Comment: I have just try the actionListener, and ajax="false" on <p:menuItem>, and not worked

Comment: See, action="" should be used with ajax="false", and is most recommended for when page navigation occurs. And actionListener="" should be used with ajax="true" and is recommended for when there is no page navigation. So when you use actionListener, you need to run an update="" the components that need to be updated.

Comment: declared navBean as application scope then try

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your browser for any JS errors? Im getting a "TypeError: b is undefined" in Firebug while trying to replicate this issue. It seems to be related to Primefaces 5.x version. When i rollback to version 4.0 it works fine.